# C# Cambiar accion del enter en DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Quiero cambiar la acción predeterminada para que no salte de linea el código, lo que quiero conseguir es que al tocar el <kbd>Enter</kbd> seleccione esa fila y devuelva un ok.

```
if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
{
    this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Comment: Que problema tienes con el código que has puesto?

Comment: Que salta una linea y entonces devuelve la de abajo del datagrid no la que quiero... Y no seria una solucion poner rows-1

Comment: Entonces lo unico que se me ocurre es deshabilitar el salto de linea predeterminado que mete el datagridview al pulsar el enter, pero no encuentro como hacerlo

Comment: Intenta añadir despues de `this.DialogResult...` lo siguiente: `e.Handled = true`

Comment: No, no funciona ..

Comment: KeyPress simplemente

Comment: Bien, gracias .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para evitar que el evento de pulsación del <kbd>enter</kbd> llegue al `DataGridView`, lo que debes hacer es controlar el evento `KeyDown` del `DataGridView` y poner en él `e.Handled=true;`:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me estaba volviendo loco muchisimas gracias!!!!